# passing subprocess output to multiprocessing function

Tags: python, list, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying two run the below to functions in parallel however one of the functions needs to be passed as a parameter to the other

Function 1:

```
def beginRecvTest():

  incoming = Popen("receivetest -f=/pcan33".split(), stdout = PIPE)
  processing = iter(incoming.stdout.readline, "")
  lines = list(processing)
  print processing
  return lines
```

Function 2:

```
def readByLine():


  i = 0
  while (i < len(lines)):
    system("clear")

    if(lines[i][0].isdigit()):
        line = lines[i].split()
        dictAdd(line)
    else:
        next


    print ; print "-" *80
    for _i in mydict.keys():
        printMsg(mydict, _i)

    print "Keys: ", ;  print mydict.keys()
    print ; print "-" *80
    sleep(0.3)
    i += 1
```

Function call:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

   process1 = Process(target=beginRecvTest)
   process1.start()
   process2 = Process(target=readByLine, args=(process1,))
   process2.start()
   process1.join()
   process2.join()
```

Unforunately I'm not sure how to pass this as a parameter and the code in process1 seems to hang at:

```
lines = list(processing)
```

for some reason, the program needs to pass the lines that have already been read into a list to process2 whilst still reading and sorting in process1.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing something else. But rather similar. I found this somewhere else and modified it a bit to make it work.

So you make 2 Queues and a lot of processes work on the first queue and fill the second.

I had trouble to make the writer stay alive. So i added a safeguard, a None at the end of the second queue.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
from random import uniform

def doCalculation(par):
    t = uniform(0,2)
    sleep(t)
    return par * par  # just to simulate some calculation

def feed(queue, parlist):
    for par in parlist:
            queue.put(par)

def calc(queueIn, queueOut):
    while True:
        try:
            par = queueIn.get(block = False)
            print "calculating ", par
            res = doCalculation(par)
            queueOut.put((par,res))
        except:
            break

def write(queue, fname):
    fhandle = open(fname, "w")
    breaks=0
    while True:
        try:
            par, res = queue.get(block = False)
            print "writing ", par
            # if par is None terminate the while loop / then we know the queue is empty for sure
            if par is None:
                break
            print >>fhandle, "TEST", par, res
        except:
            # could terminate the writer process prematurely if the queue gets empty in between
            sleep(0.01)
    fhandle.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nthreads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    print nthreads
    fname = "foo"

    workerQueue = Queue() 
    writerQueue = Queue()

    parlist = range(100) #[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    # fill the workerQueue (1 Processes)
    feedProc = Process(target = feed , args = (workerQueue, parlist))
    # start working Processes (nthreads) that work on workerQueue and send to writerQueue
    calcProc = [Process(target = calc , args = (workerQueue, writerQueue)) for i in range(nthreads)]
    # work on writerQueue (1 Processes)
    writProc = Process(target = write, args = (writerQueue, fname))

    feedProc.start()
    for p in calcProc:
        p.start()
    writProc.start()

    # Join Subprocesses with the Main one again
    feedProc.join ()
    for p in calcProc:
        p.join()       

    # terminate writer queue manually 
    # add empty element to the queue
    writerQueue.put( (None,None) )

    # terminate now or close if you continue after this!
```

I guess you can adapt it to your needs.

best wishes